# why does typesript not respond to type when promis?

Tags: typescript, types

I get a correct result although there should be an error. why does TypeScript not respond to type when promise? I have written the number value to the string variable, and I don't get an error, why is this happening?

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-elgamal-4lbin2

```js
    const BEApi = new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve({
        string: 123
      });
    });
    type MyDataType = {
      string: string;
    };
    
    let myData: MyDataType | null = null;
    
    const myResponce = async () => {
      myData = (await BEApi) as MyDataType;
      console.log(myData);
    };
    
    myResponce();
```

Comment: Why should there be an error?

Comment: I wrote the string type to the number and I don't get an error why is this happening?

Comment: there is a type MyDataType. It has a variable with a value of 132. This variable is a number. 
here I make the connection myData = (await BEApi) as MyDataType. Why is there no error? I substitute a number instead of a string and typesript should write an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) tells TypeScript that a value **is** the specified type.

It explicitly overrides all type checks.

You said `(await BEApi) as MyDataType` and TypeScript trusts you.

---

I recommend avoiding `as`. A better way to describe the types would be to specify that `new Promise` should resolve as `MyDataType`.

This will cause TypeScript to report an error when you try to resolve it with a value that does not conform to that type.

```js
type MyDataType = {
  string: string;
};

const BEApi = new Promise<MyDataType>((resolve) => {
  resolve({
    string: 123
  });
});

let myData: MyDataType | null = null;

const myResponce = async () => {
  myData = await BEApi;
  console.log(myData);
};

myResponce();
```